# Убрать отображение консоли при запуске go приложения

Tags: golang

Есть возможность убрать отображения консоли при выполнение приложения.
Сейчас при запуске на миг отображается консоль,очень неприятно,хочется от этого избавится.

Comment: Вроде `go build -ldflags -H=windowsgui` должно сработать

Comment: Или если хочется сильно извратиться :) то (читаем)[https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/Debug/pe-format#windows-subsystem]. Бинарным редакторам читаете байт 0x3C к этому значению добавляете (4+20+68) и там должен быть байт со значеним 0x03 меняете его на 0x02.

Answer (score 1):

Вот такой вариант работает в **go1.10.1 windows/amd64**

```
go build -ldflags "-s -H windowsgui" main.go
```